# Distinct Linq search query

Tags: c#, linq, distinct-values

I have a table say TABLEA

| ID | Description | regNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | iphone | 9890 |
| 002 | iphone pro max | 9890 |
| 003 | iphone se | 9890 |
| 004 | iphone | 7847 |
| 008 | samsung | 9432 |
| 009 | samsung s10 | 9432 |
| 010 | orange | 34 |

**Problem**
Get all the `regNumber` that matches and display as a consolidated data (single data)

**Acceptable solution**
For example if someone search for an id with '001' get all the SAME `regNumber` like this

| Desc | regNumber | Total number of reg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| iphone | 9890 | 3 |

**Part Solution**
I have listed all the `regNumber` like this:

```
var listOfRegs = _db.Table.Select(x=>x.regNumber).toList();
```

I now need to find a way to iterate this list to group how many times a `regNumber` matches which is the problem I'm having but something like this:

```
foreach(var i in listOfRegs)
{
  //find a way to group/list distinct regNumbers which is why I'm asking?

}
```

It's easier if the query was to search for the `regNumber` which you can pass through the action something like this:

```
var listOfRegs = _db.TABLE.where (a.regNumber== 
model.regNumberSearched).Select(x=>x.regNumber).Distinct().ToList();

//this works fine
```

But the problem is that I'm not passing that regNumber Instead just got a list of `regNumber` that matches 'ID' from the table and as u can see from the table ID is always
unique so passing `model.id` (the id being pass) will always only output a unique `regNumber`
rather than counting all matches.
so how do I proceed please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=net-6.0) and project the result into an anonymous type:

```
var groupedData = _db.Table.GroupBy(x => x.regNumber)  // group by regNumber
                           .Select(g => new 
                           { 
                               Desc = g.First().Desc,  // use the first Desc
                               RegNumber = g.Key,      // RegNumber is the group Key 
                               Count = g.Count()       // number of elements in group
                           })
                           .ToList();
```

This will give you output similar to:

| Desc | RegNumber | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| iphone | 9890 | 3 |
| samsung | 9432 | 2 |
| orange | 34 | 1 |

---

If you have a list of Table IDs to filter on, say `listOfIds`, you can filter that first to get all associated `regNumber`, then use the list of `regNumber`s to group the data:

```
List<int> listOfIds = // your list of Table Ids from the DB
// get your list of regNumbers based on table IDs
var listOfRegNumbers = _db.Table.Where(t => listOfIds.Any(id => id == t.Id))
                                .Select(t => t.regNumber)
                                .Distinct();
// group the data
var groupedData = _db.Table.Where(x => listOfRegNumbers.Any(id => id == x.regNumber))
                           .GroupBy(x => x.regNumber)  // group by regNumber
                           .Select(g => new 
                           { 
                               Desc = g.First().Desc,  // use the first Desc
                               RegNumber = g.Key,      // RegNumber is the group Key 
                               Count = g.Count()       // number of elements in group
                           })
                           .ToList();
```

However, I not sure that's required for your case. Using `List<string>` would work above too, depending on your data type of the column.

Here is an [online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f31Nqp) (adapted from Prasad Telkikar's - thank you!).

Comment: Hi @Haldo, your solution is absolutely correct, but if you look at problem statement, OP says *Get all the regNumber that **matches** the condition*

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I think that's because OP is using a list of `regNumber`s that they created in this step: `var listOfRegs = _db.Table.Select(x=>x.regNumber).toList();` then OP is trying to use that to that to filter the table again. Using my solution OP does not need to filter initially. That's my interpretation anyway

Comment: +1 for your efforts. Atleast I am not clear here, about `id` to be search is with OP or not?
BTW your second query will return 0 elements because `listOfIds.Any(id == x.regNumber)` this will never be `true`

Comment: I see what you're saying, I missed the part that OP wanted to filter based on the Table.ID field. I *think* what I have now might work for OP.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, really appreciate it. but Sorry my bad maybe the question wasn't clear at first so, I have edited the question to be more specific. Could u see if you can help again? thank you.

Comment: @Jeff You've completely changed the question. Initially you said *"say I have a TableA..."* but you actually have 2 tables?! I've already spent time on your original question. Sorry, but it's not the same question or even similar to the original. Maybe you should consider rolling back the edit (so there's at least a valid answer) then asking your new/actual question as a separate new question. When you ask a question please make sure it's the actual question you want an answer to, otherwise it just wastes everyones time :(

Comment: I understand, your answer is valid but just doesn’t fit the two tables, so I’ll of course roll back the edit and post as a separate question. Thank you for your initial answer, I appreciate it and voted it.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff! Good luck with your new question

Comment: @Haldo, how do u join the two tables though? Please do u have a clue mate?